# String to timestamp casting in pyspark

Tags: python, json, pyspark, timestamp

I am completely new to pyspark, I have a input file('|' separated) which has values like

`|2013-12-20 00:00:00|19:00:00|
 |2013-12-21 00:00:00|18:00:00|`

I have a json to apply schema on this input dataframe, but when I specify the datatypes as all Strings using below JSON :

```
{
  "type" : "struct",
  "fields" : [ {

    "name" : "date_generated",
    "type" : "string",
    "nullable" : true,
    "metadata" : {}
  },  {
    "name" : "time_generated",
    "type" : "string",
    "nullable" : true,
    "metadata" : {}
  }
 ]
}
```

I can apply this schema(both string) to my dataframe and and read it also ,works fine.
But when I use the 'timestamp' as json , it applies the schema on dataframe but when i read that i an getting below Error :

```
field date_arrested: TimestampType can not accept object '2013-12-20 00:00:00' in type <class 'str'>
```

Below is the pyspark code :

```
inputDf = spark.read.option("delimiter", "|").csv(inout_file_path)
with open('schema.json', 'r') as S:  # path to schema file
    saved_schema = json.load(S)

targetDf = spark.createDataFrame(inputDf.rdd, StructType.fromJson(saved_schema))
targetDf.printSchema()
```

Input new JSON :

```
{
      "type" : "struct",
      "fields" : [ {

        "name" : "date_generated",
        "type" : "string",
        "nullable" : true,
        "metadata" : {}
      },  {
        "name" : "time_generated",
        "type" : "string",
        "nullable" : true,
        "metadata" : {}
      }
     ]
    }
```

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Why are you converting `df -> rdd -> df`?

Comment: @pissall as i need to apply the schema on my DF, I changed it to RDD.